# Typescript - use this in arrow ( callback ) function - mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, schema, this

How can i use this keyword in arrow ( callback function ). I am creating mongoose Schema in class. Check it out.

```
class UserSchema {
    private userSchema: Schema;

    constructor() {
        this.setSchema();
    }

    public getUserSchema(): Schema {
        return this.userSchema;
    }

    private setSchema() {
        this.userSchema = new Schema({
            createdAt: Date,
            uptadedAt: Date,
            email: String,
            password: String
        });

        this.preSave();
    }

    private preSave() {
        this.userSchema.pre('save', (next: NextFunction) => {
            /*
                Here
            */
            if(this.createdAt)
                this.createdAt = new Date();
            next();
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see i have added comment. I want to access createdAt to add Date to variable, but i cannot access this keyword :(
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with Mongoose but this is how I usually work with arrow functions in a class: just create a new method and refer to that. It prevents "callback pyramids" and `this` keeps referring to the class instance

```
class UserSchema {
    private preSave() {
        this.userSchema.pre('save', (next: NextFunction) => this.doSomething(next))
    }
    private doSomething(next:NextFunction) {
        console.log(this)
        console.log("this should be the UserSchema instance")
        if(this.createdAt) {
                this.createdAt = new Date()
        }
        next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error. Getting "Property createdAt doesn't exist on type UserSchema". Hmm.. when i try to console.log(this.userSchema.createdAt) in setSchema getting same error. Is smth wrong with this code?

Comment: Ok found the solution. Just use this.userSchema.get('createdAt') and set :)
Anyway thanks for help